# Can't get resolution higher than 1080×480

Tags: graphics

I use windows 10 before the Ubuntu and in windows my integrated graphics (Intel 82945G) was working fine with 1920×1080 resolution but after Ubuntu the screen is fixed at 1080×480 and everything is messed up now please can anyone help me ?